# Document Management System

Tags: spring, vaadin, alfresco, document-management

At the company I work for, we are developing a billing web application with Spring and Vaadin. The trouble is that the number of files to manage is becoming too large; bill,offers contract, etc. We currently store each document as a file on the server, but in this way it is too hard to manage them. This is tedious and error-prone, and it also means we lack any sort of security for accessing these documents.

Now, I'm looking a Document Management System to manage this document. I saw Alfresco Document Management, but I don't know how to integrate it with my application.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [CMIS](http://chemistry.apache.org/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alfresco has [REST API](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_RESTful_API_Reference), so you can use it in your Spring + Vaadin application. Spring has [RestTemplate](http://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate/) based on Jackson who will help you with REST client implementation.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to integrate with alfresco. My two favorite ways to integrate with Alfresco are:

1. Using the CMIS api 
   http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS
2. Using your own custom webscripts or java back end webscripts. These allow you to quickly develop your own rest api with alfresco. 
   http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Fconcepts%2Fws-architecture.html

There are many different ways to integrate. They have webdav, cifs, ftp, and several other ways to integrate. Here is some documentation from alfresco about it

http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Fconcepts%2Fintegration-options.html